# Why do I get a a "Public member 'Field' on type 'String' not found." exception when converting my datatable rows to a List(Of Object) in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, linq

I've got a VB.Net app which is attempting to convert the rows in a DataTable to a generic list of objects using Linq.

**Here is my class (object) definition:**

```
Public Class Sample
    Public Property Field1 As String = ""
    Public Property Field2 As String = ""
End Class
```

**Here is the code snippet I'm using to convert to a List(of T):**

```
Dim dt as DataTable = ' Results of some query
Dim samples As New List(Of Sample)

If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
   samples = (From dr In dt.AsEnumerable() _
             Select New Sample() _
                With {.Field1 = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)(0)), "Missing Field1", dr.Field(Of String)(0)) _
                      .Field2 = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)(1)), "Missing FIeld2", dr.Field(Of String)(1))} _
             ).ToList()
End If
```

The code compiles fine, but I get the following exception:

> "Public member 'Field2' on type 'String' not found."

If I only do 1 field, the statement works correctly.
If I reverse the order of the fields within the "With" clause, I get the following exception:

> Public member 'Field1' on type 'String' not found

.

What am I doing wrong?
Is there an issue with my Linq definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `With` the properties of class should be separated by **comma**.

Give a try as shown in below prototype.

```
Select New Sample With {.Field1 = ....., .Field2 =........}
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet is missing a comma between the field definitions.

```
With {.Field1 = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)(0)), "Missing Field1", dr.Field(Of String)(0)) _
                      .Field2 = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)(1)), "Missing FIeld2", dr.Field(Of String)(1))}
```

Should be:

```
With {.Field1 = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)(0)), "Missing Field1", dr.Field(Of String)(0)), _
                      .Field2 = IIf(String.IsNullOrEmpty(dr.Field(Of String)(1)), "Missing FIeld2", dr.Field(Of String)(1))}
```